# "I heard the clock strike ten": why not "striked ten"?

Tags: past-tense, infinitives, present-tense, subordinate-clauses, verbs-of-perception

> I heard the clock **strike** ten.

Why is **strike** in the simple present in this sentence?

What are the conditions for using a simple present verb after a past tense verb to talk about the past?

Comment: It's the *infinitive* - simple present would be *"I heard the clock **strikes** ten"*, which would mean something very different (and would need a fairly contrived context to make sense).

Comment: But note that the *past*, *"I heard the clock **struck** ten"*, also has a different meaning.

Comment: It also has a different structure: *that* is optional in *"I heard [(that) the clock **struck** ten]"*, but *"I heard [the clock **strike** ten]"* can't have *that* at all.

Comment: In case non-native speakers are wondering about the meanings alluded to by FumbleFingers or Peter Shor, their examples would basically mean "I heard someone say that the clock strikes ten" or "I heard someone say that the clock struck ten"; both sentences would describe *things that were said* about the clock, rather than describing the sound of the clock itself.

Comment: Since no one else has mentioned it: "striked" isn't correct in any case; the past of "strike" is "struck" (strike is an irregular verb).

Comment: I heard the clock strike ten. - This is interpreted as the speaker PERSONALLY heard the chime of the clock.

I heard the clock struck ten. - This can be (normally is?) interpreted as hearsay. That is, the speaker was told the clock chimed at ten, but may or may not have personally heard the clock strike ten. The complication here is that the act of being told something occurred and the act of hearing the occurrence can both use 'heard'. Compare with: "I saw the boy run into the street" with "I heard the boy ran into the street".

Answer (score 7):

*VERBS OF PERCEPTION* can take a clause with the verb in the infinitive or *plain form*. Verbs of perception are verbs about how our bodies detect things in the world. Some examples are:

- *hear, listen, see, watch, look, taste, feel, sense*

If these clauses take a verb in the plain form, then the pronoun before the verb will always be accusative (an 'object' pronoun). It does not matter what tense the verb of perception is in:

- I heard her leave the building
- I listened to her tell her story.
- I saw him jump over the elephant.
- I 'll be watching them clean the building.
- Look at him run!
- I  could literally literally taste it go sour as I drank it.
- I felt her touch my arm.
- I sensed him move the table sightly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you give an example for *taste*?

Comment: @snailboat Duly added! :)

Comment: @Araucaria: The "taste" example seems a bit contrived; I think it would be more natural to "taste" nouns, e.g. "After licking the orange layer for a couple minutes, I began to taste the strawberry one."

Comment: @supercat Well, I was thinking about a lolly, yes - actually Veruca Salt - if you know the book, then you'll know what I mean! Your example's better, clearer, as an example of a verb *taste* (but *orange* and *strawberry* are nouns nonetheless!) More pertinent, though, is that we need an example of the verb *taste* which takes an infinitival clause ... otherwise it's not relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: @Araucaria: My point was that I can't think of any situations where using "taste" with an infinitive clause would sound "natural"; if you can come up with one I'd like to see it (as would snailboat, presumably).

Comment: @supercat How about *try this lolly, you can taste it change from ...* or *Drinking yak milk in this heat is disgusting, you can literally taste it go sour as you drink it*.

Comment: @supercat I suppose the question is: can you find one where a *present* tense sounds natural - and where it means the same thing?

Comment: @Araucaria: I like the "go sour" example better; unlike your example using "change", the later example seems more natural with the infinitive construction than with any other wording.

Comment: @supercat OK, I'll take your advice there and substitute it in. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

I'd say here the pattern is:

> special verb + direct object + infinitive - to

For example:

> As soon as Theodore *felt* the rain *splatter* on his hot, dusty skin...[(Source)](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/infinitive.htm)

So, in the above sentence we wouldn't normally say ".....felt the rain splattered on his...". Unless we use "that" in that sentence, which would completely change the sentence's meaning.

In your example if you think that it should be 'struck' not 'strike' then you would need "that" in your sentence which would also change your sentence's meaning.

Other examples like your sentence could be [(here)](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/infinitive.htm):

1) She **made** him **take** her out for an expensive dinner.

2) I **saw** my friends **mount** the Kumba, a frightening roller coaster

3) Rachel went to the airport to **watch** passenger planes **take off** and land

Comment: Didn't you mean to put **watch** in bold in the last example, not *went*

Answer (score 3):

Michael Swan writes in "Practical English Usage", topic 281.2, that certain verbs are followed by an **object** ("clock") and then by an **infinitive** without "**to**" (clock *strike* ten; not *to strike* ten).

He writes that such verbs include *see, hear, feel, watch and notice* ("verbs of perception") and *let and make*.

There's a great example with *heard*, a [poem](http://unix.cc.wmich.edu/~cooneys/poems/housman.clock.html) by A. E. Housman:

> He stood, and **heard** the **steeple**
>   **Sprinkle** the quarters on the morning town.
>   One, two, three, four, to market-place and people
>   It **tossed** them down.

**Sprinkle**, the infinitive form without "to" (it's called "bare infinitive").

Note that the verb **tossed** is in the past tense, because it is not included in a similar structure (let/make/hear + object + verb), but works as the only verb in its sentence.

We can rephrase to make the **tossed** assume the infinitive form **toss**:

> He also **noticed** the steeple **toss** them down.
>   He also **let** it **toss** them down.
>   He also **watched** it **toss** them down.
>   He also **felt** it **toss** them down.

In passive versions of the same structure, we use the infinitive with **to**:

> The steeple was heard **to** toss the quarters down.
>   The steeple was made **to** toss the quarters down.

If you want to get into the intricacies of grammar, **strike** in your example is a [non-finite verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonfinite_verb).

When we use a verb in a non-finite form, we don't place it in the past tense or in the future. In your kind of sentence, we can only switch it to the form with the **-ing** ending, to stress the fact that the action is repetitive or takes place over a length of time:

> I heard the clock **striking** so long I doubted it would stop.