# Past tense confusion

Tags: past-tense

> But I was grateful that he helped me **convince** Jared there was time to make the raid and get back before a decision was made about Kyle.

Can anyone explain to me when it's not necessary to add 'ed' to the root word "convince" in the above sentence?

Comment: "convince" is used in the infinitive in your example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive

There is an implied "to" before "convince", i.e. "he helped me to convince"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help to do something or help do something?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47221/help-to-do-something-or-help-do-something)

Comment: I don't think so, James.  That question concerns whether a full or bare infinitive is an appropriate object complement, given a specific governing verb.  This question concerns the reason that the object complement cannot be a finite past-tense form, or the method by which OP can recognize a bare infinitive object complement.

Comment: Related, but not (at present) a very good duplicate, as "helped" is not mentioned: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37060/i-heard-the-clock-strike-ten-why-not-striked-ten