# What is "leave" in the sentence "We saw Fred leave"?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, verbs-of-perception

Words "leave" and "arrive" belong to which part of speech (noun or bare infinitive) in the following sentences:

> We saw Fred leave.
>
> Did you hear them arrive?

Comment: Both *leave* and *arrive* are verb. They are part of a subordinate non-finite clause. We call it infinitive clause. An infinitive clause is generally introduced by a subordinator *to* (we often call it infinitive marker). But here it's grammatical to omit the infinitive marker, we call it bare-infinitive clause. few verbs like *see*, *hear* etc licenses bare infinitive clause.

Comment: Thank you Man_From_India. @snailplane adds verbs-of-perception tag and I googled that tag and find https://www.englishgrammar.org/verbs-perception/. now my question is this structure is unique to the verbs of perceptions?

Comment: Verbs of perception generally licenses bare infinitive clauses. Notice that in your example sentences the verbs of your matrix clauses are *saw* and *hear*. They both are verb of perception. They expresses "perception".

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37060/i-heard-the-clock-strike-ten-why-not-striked-ten There's a good answer here.

Comment: They are both bare infinitival verbs. "See" and "hear" are catenative verbs, and "leave" and "arrive" are non-finite clauses function as their catenative complements.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for the part of speech. They are all verbs functioning as catenative verbs.

[Verbs of perception](https://www.englishgrammar.org/verbs-perception/) are idiosyncratic in that they can take a bare-infinitival clause as a complement. So both sentences are fine.

---

Additional information

1. Causative-*let* and *-make* take only a bare infinitival complement.

> He made me cry.<sup>OK</sup>
>
> He made me to cry.<sup>not OK</sup>

However, *make* requires a *to-infinival complement* when it's passive.

> He was made to repeat the whole story.

2. *"to help"* can take either to-infinitive or bare-infinitive. The to-infinitive version is rather formal and quite common in British English:

> That helps (to) propel me to victory.

Comment: Yes, though *make* takes a *to*-infinitival complement when it's passive.

Answer (score 1):

> *We saw Fred leave*.
>
> *Did you hear them arrive?*

These are both catenative constructions.

"See" and "hear" are catenative verbs, and "leave" and "arrive" are bare infinitival non-finite clauses functioning as catenative complements. The intervening objects "Fred" and "them" belong syntactically in the matrix clauses, not the infinitivals, though they are, of course, *understood* as the subjects of the latter.

Comment: If only there was an English translation of this answer for non-linguists, I might have a clue as to what any of this means.  I'm a native speaker and have to wonder whether this can mean more to English language learners than it does to me.  Just sayin'.